# Scripted generating then loading rasters to PostGIS - raster2pgsql phantom

Tags: postgis, raster

(Ubuntu server 18)

It seems that raster2pgsql is included in the postgis package but I can't find it separately to download either source or binary. Supposedly there's an executable somewhere in the postgresql lib folders. After reading some things I have the idea that it's not default in the installation or when compiling and maybe I won't find it if I used the extension script distributed with postgresql. How do I add it?

That said, the intention is to generate raster data and load it using Python scripts, so a gdal driver might be more convenient since we are already using gdal.

The script runs on a separate machine from the pg instance, if that matters.

What's the most straightforward way to pipe large volumes of raster data into postgis on a remote box?

Answer (score 0):

On my Windows 10 it defaults to C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\11\bin for the raster2pgsql.exe. If you get the raster2pgsql most of it should also run on Ubuntu.

I made a Python script for loading all tiff in a folder to PostGIS using raster2pgsql.

```
"""
    Import all raster files in folder to PostgreSQL PostGIS
"""
import os


def run_raster2pgsql(file_path):
    file_name = os.path.basename(file_path)     # strip path
    file_name = os.path.splitext(file_name)[0]  # strip extension

    dbname = 'sandbox'
    schema = 'tilstandsvurdering'
    host = 'localhost'
    user = 'postgres'
    pw = 'xxx'
    port = '5432'

    bin_path = r"C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\11\bin"

    cmd = f"""
set PGPASSWORD={pw}&&SET PATH=%PATH%;{bin_path}&& "raster2pgsql.exe" -I -C "{file_path}" -F {schema}.{file_name} | psql -U {user} -d {dbname} -h {host} -p {port}
        """

    #print(cmd)
    os.system(cmd)
    
    print('************Done with file')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    raster_dir = r'C:\data\Tilstandsvurderinger\Magasinkoter\export'
    raster_ext = 'tiff'

    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(raster_dir):
        tiff_files = [file for file in files if os.path.splitext(file)[1] == '.tiff']
        for filename in tiff_files:
            filepath = os.path.join(root, filename)
            run_raster2pgsql(filepath)
        break   # no recursive walk
```